# Html formatted text in clipboard with <li> tags not pasting within specified range using paste special in C#

Tags: c#, html, excel

I am working on writing formatted text to excel. I am using paste special method as shown in below code:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= rowUsed; i++)
{
    cellRng = sheet.Cells[i, 4];
    if (value.Count!=0)
    {
        //pasting after copying to clipboard
        CopyToClipBoard(value[i]);
        //selecting the worksheet
        sheet.Select();
        //selecting the range to paste
        cellRng.Select();
        sheet.PasteSpecial(Type.Missing, false, false,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,false);
        sheet.Select();
        cellRng.Select();                                        
    }                                                            
}
```

The paste special works fine for formatting like Bold, Italics, Colors except when the html content contains spacing or bullets.

If spacing are there it is not maintained and in case of bullets the values are getting written to the next cell depending on the spacing between them.

[image]

Kindly help me to paste the contents the same spacing as well as bullet into the specified range. I also read from https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-pasting.htm that

```
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteType.xlPasteValues, _                    
Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd, _ 
                     SkipBlanks:=False, _ 
                     Transpose:=False
```

will paste a Range from the Clipboard into the specified range. When I tired it it throws the "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed" exception.

Thank you.

Comment: Tabs are column separators, so you'll need to remove all tabs first.

Comment: Your question formation is not good. Use more clear screenshots vertically so people not need to scroll down.

Comment: @Arvindraja I have updated the image. Kindly check it.

Comment: @Davesoft Thank you. When I paste bullet contents manually or spacing, they are maintained correctly in excel. Is a modification of paste special arguments needed?